# High voltage peaks when using mxo45hs-3c-1m0000

Tags: analog, analysis

I am using an [mxo45hs-3c-1m0000](http://www.digikey.com/Web%20Export/Supplier%20Content/CTS_8006/PDF/cts-pi-oscillator-MXO45-MXO45T.pdf?redirected=1) quartz in order to produce a 0-5V square signal (1MHz). On the oscilloscope, the signal I get is a square signal, but there are important sine waves in the plateau. I put a 1uF capacitor in parallel with the imput so the resulting signal gets perfectly square, but I don't know how to get rid of that noise. If anyone has an idea on the way to attenuate the sine waves, let me know!

Comment: Could you perhaps post a picture of what you see? Also, a link to the datasheet would be useful. Also, a circuit schematic of how you're using it.

Answer (score 1):

These ICs require decoupling capacitors as physically close to the input connectors as possible. 0.01uF to 1uF are normal, with 0.1uF being industry standard. The sharp rise time causes stray inductances to ring out in the output without decoupling caps to compensate.